# How to install brand new clincher tires on triban wheel

Tags: road-bike, tire, tire-lever

I ride a Triban RC120 disc, stock wheels (tubeless ready) and tires.

Had a flat before but, at some cost, managed to put the original tire (700x28c) back in, after replacing inner tube.

I bought a pair or Pirelli PZero Race (700x28c) but cannot put them on. I have some standard-looking tire levers (with clip to secure them to the wheel) that I used before on my MTB:
[image]

And a *installer/remover* thingy that I bought when I was having trouble putting the original tire back on:
[image]

I watched several videos on youtube but nothing seems to help.

Can you suggest anything that might help the tire become easier to apply?

Comment: I think the main problem here is "tubeless ready". Anything that is "tubeless ready" means it's almost impossible to get any tire on it. If you use inner tubes, you may even puncture a tube in the process. With tubeless system obviously inner tube puncture isn't a consideration, but getting it sealed and maintaining enough sealant is a constant trouble, and should you ever have a puncture that requires a tube at the roadside, it's almost impossible to put that tube in.

Comment: *Anything that is "tubeless ready" means it's almost impossible to get any tire on it* This is completely false. I regularly install and remove fresh road and MTB tubeless tires without any tools, and my upper body strength & hand strength aren't anything to write home about

Comment: @juhist *With tubeless system...getting it sealed and maintaining enough sealant is a constant trouble* also completely false. In my experience, it takes about 10 minutes to set up a rim from tape to valve to inflation + sealant. 3 flat tires in well over 30,000 km of cycling (evenly split between road and MTB, so 2x the time on MTB) is definitely _not_ a constant trouble compared to the alternative.

Comment: @juhist *should you ever have a puncture that requires a tube at the roadside, it's almost impossible to put that tube in*. Again, false. Without tools, I managed to get a tube into my three flat tires. In one case, unthreading the tubeless valve was a hassle, but still accomplished by hand. In two of the cases, it was a bit of a mess with the sealant.

Answer (score 2):

1. Tire levers are for taking tires off, not putting them on.
2. Some tire/rim combinations are just difficult. If the rim was manufactured on the large side of manufacturing tolerances, and the tire on the small side, they'll be a tight fit.
3. I don't know what the videos you watched recommended, but there's usually a trough in the center of the rim. Once you get most of the tire worked on, work the bead into the trough to create a little slack for getting on the remainder.
4. [Tire jacks](http://www.koolstop.com/images/Accessories/KS-TBJ%20IMAGE.jpg) are helpful for getting stubborn tires on.

Comment: I find tyre levers very helpful for getting tyres on. Usually I can get them on without levers by really making sure it sits in the rim bed (and because I have strong fingers from climbing). In cases where that’s not enough levers are helpful.

Comment: Tyre levers are very useful for installing tyres. Your first statement is a false story to prevent the inexperienced from ruining tubes, breaking levers and getting stroppy.

Comment: @Adam To list a few videos that were recommended when dealing with tight tires:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZXP6rwkSqk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ommc1njaNE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWPUL67IJU0

Luckily, after almost giving up, I read that soapy water worked with some people with the same problem. It made the task a little bit easier, and I've managed to install the stubborn tire. I'm hoping that after some rides it will become somewhat easier to fit back in, if needed.